# When do Russians use the expression "Ты смеешься надо мной"?

Tags: словоупотребление, значения, выражения

What does that expression mean and when would you use it?

Answer (score 2):

They don't really. It means "are you kidding me", but I have never heard anyone say that, except when (poorly) translating an American movie.
Something like "ты шутишь?" or "ты смеешься?" can be heard somewhat more often in that context, but are still a bit too academic. A simple "Да ну?" would be more appropriate in most cases.

Comment: is there any russian expression similar to "You smile under me"? Because I have been told that there is a Russian expression with such translation but I can't remember it

Comment: I  am afraid, I don't even know what it means in English :)
I mean, maybe, I could guess, but I have never heard or seen it used anywhere.

Comment: "Да ты гонишь!" - slang, informal or even rude form.
"Прикалываешься, да?" - informal.
"Не смешно" - more formal.

Comment: The phrase "смеяться над ____" is given in the <i>Dictionary of Spoken Russian</i> (1945) as a translation of "to laugh at". I agree with Dima that the expression is not used much in conversation. I think it is used though to explain the English phrase.

Answer (score 2):

It can be used as expression of disbelief or asking if person is joking (also with negative tone). In this case the meaning will consist of 2 parts (from [here](http://www.vedu.ru/expdic/32557/)):

> над кем-чем. То же, что **насмехаться**.
>    Смеяться над глупостью.
>   *Смеяться, право, не грешно над тем, что кажется смешно (афоризм).*

It will be a kind of the same meaning as "mocking". And the second:

> перен., над кем-чем.
>   Пренебрегать кем-нибудь - чем-нибудь, не знать страха перед кем-нибудь - чем-нибудь.
>   *Смеяться над опасностью или перед лицом опасности.*

According to [Ozhegov dictionary](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F&all=x), these meanings are combined into one:

> над кем-чем; (устар.) кому-чему.
>   *Насмехаться, издеваться над кем-л., чем-л.*
>   Смеяться над собой.
>   Смеяться над глупостью.
>   Смеяться над доверчивостью.
>   Смеяться над приятелями.

It could be also used when expressing misbelief, misunderstanding of someone else taste / opinions, like asking yourself "..Who could really need these things when they are so [poorly / wrong / etc] done ?"

> " ...Старая шинель и нещегольское платье показывали в нем того человека, который с самоотвержением предан был своему труду и не имел времени заботиться о своем наряде[...] Он остановился перед лавкою и сперва *внутренно смеялся* над этими уродливыми картинами. Наконец овладело им невольное размышление: он стал думать о том, кому бы нужны были эти произведения.  "
>   *Н.В. Гоголь, "Портрет".*

The word is used in this meaning in formal talking mostly. I wouldn't say it is inappropriate to use it in friends' talk; however to soften the meaning it's better not to use "надо мной" and leave only verb:

> Эх ты, толстоносый! Сосульку, тряпку принял за важного человека! [...] Вот что обидно! Чина, звания не пощадит, и будут все скалить зубы и бить в ладоши. [...]
>   Чему смеетесь? — Над собою смеетесь!.. Эх вы!..
>   *Н. В. Гоголь. "Ревизор"*

Answer (score 0):

this just means "are you kidding?" (or even "are you f..n kidding me?!")
this is usually a negative expression and we dont use in friendly talks.